# Restore a saved neural network in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Before marking my question as duplicate, I want you to understand that I have went through a lot of questions, but none of the solutions there were able to clear my doubts and solve my problem. I have a trained neural network which I want to save, and later use this model to test this model against test dataset.

I tried saving and restoring it, but I am not getting the expected results. Restoring doesn't seem to work, maybe I am using it wrongly, it is just using the values given by the global variable initializer.

This is the code I am using for saving the model.

```
 sess.run(tf.initializers.global_variables())
#num_epochs = 7
for epoch in range(num_epochs):  
  start_time = time.time()
  train_accuracy = 0
  train_loss = 0
  val_loss = 0
  val_accuracy = 0

  for bid in range(int(train_data_size/batch_size)):
     X_train_batch = X_train[bid*batch_size:(bid+1)*batch_size]
     y_train_batch = y_train[bid*batch_size:(bid+1)*batch_size]
     sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {x:X_train_batch, y:y_train_batch,prob:0.50})  

     train_accuracy = train_accuracy + sess.run(model_accuracy, feed_dict={x : X_train_batch,y:y_train_batch,prob:0.50})
     train_loss = train_loss + sess.run(loss_value, feed_dict={x : X_train_batch,y:y_train_batch,prob:0.50})

  for bid in range(int(val_data_size/batch_size)):
     X_val_batch = X_val[bid*batch_size:(bid+1)*batch_size]
     y_val_batch = y_val[bid*batch_size:(bid+1)*batch_size]
     val_accuracy = val_accuracy + sess.run(model_accuracy,feed_dict = {x:X_val_batch, y:y_val_batch,prob:0.75})
     val_loss = val_loss + sess.run(loss_value, feed_dict = {x:X_val_batch, y:y_val_batch,prob:0.75})

  train_accuracy = train_accuracy/int(train_data_size/batch_size)
  val_accuracy = val_accuracy/int(val_data_size/batch_size)
  train_loss = train_loss/int(train_data_size/batch_size)
  val_loss = val_loss/int(val_data_size/batch_size)


  end_time = time.time()


  saver.save(sess,'./blood_model_x_v2',global_step = epoch)
```

After saving the model, the files are written in my working directory something like this.

blood_model_x_v2-2.data-0000-of-0001 
   blood_model_x_v2-2.index
   blood_model_x_v2-2.meta

Similarly, v2-3, so on to v2-6, and then a 'checkpoint' file. I then tried restoring it using this code snippet (after initializing),but getting different results from the expected one. What am I doing wrong ?

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('blood_model_x_v2-5.meta')
saver.restore(test_session,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

Comment: What did you expect and what did happen?

Comment: After I trained the model, I saved the model and tested it. Got an accuracy of around 50% but when I create a new session, and restore the model and test it, I get around 20 - 25% accuracy (my problem has 4 classes). I expect a similar accuracy as I am getting while testing.

Comment: The way you restore the model is ok but notice that the variables to restore do not have to have been initialized, as restoring is itself a way to initialize variables.

Comment: That gives me 'Attempt to use uninitialized value' error.

Comment: The problem is here! you initialize the model randomly and not load checkpoints at all.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you perhaps explain with a code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#restore):

> **Restore**
>   Restores previously saved variables.
>
> This method runs the ops added by the constructor for restoring
>   variables. It requires a session in which the graph was launched. The
>   **variables to restore do not have to have been initialized**, as
>   restoring is itself a way to initialize variables.

Let's see an example:

We save the model similar to this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Prepare to feed input, i.e. feed_dict and placeholders
w1 = tf.placeholder("float", name="w1")
w2 = tf.placeholder("float", name="w2")
b1 = tf.Variable(2.0, name="bias")
feed_dict = {w1: 4, w2: 8}

# Define a test operation that we will restore
w3 = tf.add(w1, w2)
w4 = tf.multiply(w3, b1, name="op_to_restore")
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Create a saver object which will save all the variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Run the operation by feeding input
print (sess.run(w4, feed_dict))
# Prints 24 which is sum of (w1+w2)*b1

# Now, save the graph
saver.save(sess, './ckpnt/my_test_model', global_step=1000)
```

And then load the trained model with:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
# First let's load meta graph and restore weights
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./ckpnt/my_test_model-1000.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./ckpnt'))

# Now, let's access and create placeholders variables and
# create feed-dict to feed new data

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
w1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0")
w2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("w2:0")
feed_dict = {w1: 13.0, w2: 17.0}

# Now, access the op that you want to run.
op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("op_to_restore:0")

print (sess.run(op_to_restore, feed_dict))
# This will print 60 which is calculated
# using new values of w1 and w2 and saved value of b1.
```

As you can see we do not initialize our session in the restoring part. There is better way to save and restore model with [`Checkpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint) which allows you to check whether the model is restored correctly or not.

Comment: I have nearly 12-14 hidden layers. Am I supposed to restore the weights of each layer by using tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('w1:0') ?

Comment: @AmruthLakkavaram graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0") is a placeholder. You usually have a few of them. As may notice we restore bias successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much @Amir, that helps. What I was doing wrong was that I was not restoring the placeholders and operations to be restored, from the metagraph. I was freshly defining the operations and placeholders again, and I was running these freshly defined ops by feeding values in the freshly defined placeholders. That was the reason, I was getting 'Attempting to use uninitialized' error. So, when I was initializing using global_variable_initializer, I was not getting expected results.